# End process when 'No files to load' is outputted to terminal

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I have inherited a python program, which works as follows:

- Checks for files in a directory
- If present loads them into somewhere
- Once it finds no files in the directory it just prints 'No files to load' reccursively

We run it in a batch file looks like this `python python_file.py`

The problem is that I have to manually close the command line to end the task.

As a quick fix, is there a way to stop the program once `No files to load` appears in the terminal window?

Comment: use `try except:` in python

Comment: If you're not looking to modify the script, then this is a question for superuser.com. That said, if you run Python from CMD, you can send it a console Ctrl+Break event, which will kill Python without closing  the console since CMD ignores the Ctrl+Break event, and the console doesn't close as long as at least one process is attached to it. (Note that the console is hosted by conhost.exe, and cmd.exe only uses the console, exactly as python.exe. The only thing special about CMD in this case is that it ignores Ctrl+Break. For some weird reason people keep assuming CMD is the console.)

Answer (score 0):

Python `try` for python 3.6.x

```
while True:

    try:
        # file read code

    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("file not found")

        break
```